# Display every ListViewItem to another different activity

Tags: android, listview

I am having a simple listview with an ImageIcon and a Title.
Now whenever I click on my listItem I need to send this listitem to another activity. like Activity1, Activity2, Activity3 and so on....
I have read many SO answers but couldn't find a better solution for this.
My Main Activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
 AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView list;
String [] memeTitles;
String [] memeDescriptions;
int [] images = {R.drawable.img0,R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.img5};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Resources res = getResources();
    memeTitles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    VivzAdapter adapter = new VivzAdapter(this, memeTitles, images,     memeDescriptions);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    // i created this activity for first listview item but it's not working
        // other Activity class name = Activity1

        Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        startActivity(i);
  }
  }
   class VivzAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
     {
Context context;
String[] titleArray;

int [] images;
VivzAdapter(Context c, String[] titles, int imgs[], String[] desc )
{
    super(c, R.layout.single_row, R.id.textView1, titles);
    this.context= c;
    this.images=imgs;
    this.titleArray= titles;
//  this.descriptionArray = desc;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row  = convertView ;
    if (row == null)
    {
    LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
    }
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView)    row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    TextView  myTitles = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    myTitles.setText(titleArray[position]); 
    return row;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put values in your intent like this :-

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
i.putExtra("image", images[position]);
i.putExtra("title", titleArray[position]);
startActivity(i);
```

and retrieve in your other activity like this :-

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    String titlenewString= extras.getString("title");
    int imageName = extras.getInt("image");
}
```

Comment: i have add code as you mention but nothing happpen,

 Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
  i.putExtra("image", images[0]);
  i.putExtra("title", memeTitles[0]);
  startActivity(i);

Comment: Did you added my second half of code in your activity1

Comment: When you implement an interface, you need to do this also otherwise it will not get the activity reference. `list.setOnItemClickListener(this); `. write this line below your setAdapter line

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed put the different properties as different fields as Rahul suggested.

Another way in which you can send the whole view is by making a custom View which extends your ListItem's View and implements `Parcable`. Than you can put it in your Intent with `putParcable(String key, Parcable object)`

Comment: I have applied his code but nothing happen when i clicking on list items.

Comment: Looking at your code, where exactly do you assign the OnItemClickListener to the ListView?

Comment: Thanks 4 correcting me, now i have added
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
below of this line, 
list.setAdapter(adapter);
but now when i click on list item then my app is crashed!
and also "i" is giving error "int i" and "intent i" is matching.

Comment: You should give them different names, you cannot have two local variables with the same name.

Comment: i have changed variable name i.e. "intent i" into "intent j" but my app is still on crashed when i click on listitem, how i can fix it?

Comment: Now, my list View items working but it show same image View on every list item click but i want to show different images on different list items click.

Comment: What did you change in your code to make it work? Could you update your question with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

just call list.setOnItemClickListener(this); , you are not setting the listener thats why it is not working.